# How to add multiple path in $PATH variable linux?

Tags: linux, path

I want to add multiple path in $path variable like java path and php path . how to do that in linux?

I am doing something in bash_profile like :

```
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/:$AWS_AUTO_SCALING_HOME/bin
```

Comment: You probably just need to enclose right-hand side of the expression in double quotes, e.g. `PATH="..."`.

Comment: Try `PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/:$AWS_AUTO_SCALING_HOME/bin"`. It's just a guess.

Comment: I am still getting the error :
-bash: as-cmd: command not found

Comment: Then it's probably something wrong with contents of the `$PATH`, you seem to setup correctly.

Comment: please if you could help me out. I am struck since last 4 hours

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45254/discussion-between-user3086014-and-xaizek)

Answer (score 113):

`$PATH` can have several paths separated by a colon (`:`). E.g.:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/myuser/bin
```

Comment: please see i have to update bash_profile directly without exporting the path.

Comment: So what's the problem with your example? What exactly does not work?

Comment: i have installed the aws-autoscaling tool but its not working. i have followed the link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingTheCommandLineTools.html

Comment: Your usage of the $PATH variable seems correct. Can you share the specific error?

Comment: its gving me command not found error when i am typing äs-cmd"

Comment: Your example should be:

    export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/myuser/bin

Without the spaces else you get this error: "bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier"

Comment: Tried this and couldn't find any executable, not even vi or cd. Had to change it to `export PATH="$PATH~/something"`

Answer (score 12):

Set the `$PATH` environment variable to include the directory where you installed the bin directory with shell scripts and two consecutive export entries as in example.

**Example**:

```
export ANT_HOME=/path/to/ant/dir
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANT_HOME}/bin:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
```

To make them permanent entries update the bash_profile file.

Answer (score 6):

One way to add multiple executables to the $PATH variable is:

```
export PATH=/path/to/executable1:\
/path/to/executable2:\
/path/to/executable3:\
/path/to/executable4
```

If a `$PATH` already exists in `.bash_profile`, and **you want them to take precedence over executables** (like java and php), you can do:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/executable1:\
/path/to/executable2:\
/path/to/executable3:\
/path/to/executable4
```

If the path to any executable contains whitespaces, add the part `/ ... executableX` in quotes.

Once you're done making changes in your `bash_profile`, source the file in a terminal session so that changes are effective immediately:

```
source .bash_profile
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Terminal and Type `sudo gedit /etc/profile` to open system path file
2. Go to Bottom
3. - `VARIABLE_NAME1=/your/path/to/location1`
   - `VARIABLE_NAME2=/your/path/to/location2`
   - `PATH=$PATH:$VARIABLE_NAME1:\$VARIABL3_NAME2`
   - `export PATH`
4. Logout from user and Relogin

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a Mac, the best way in my opinion would be following Chamindu's answer with a slight tweak. using nano or vim whichever you prefer, but I'll use nano as it's easier for most people.

1. Open Terminal and Type `nano ~/.bash_profile` to open bash profile.
2. At the top, type or copy and paste the following:

   - `FLUTTER="/Users/MyUsername/development/flutter/bin"`
   - `VSCODE="/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"`
   - `PATH=$PATH:$FLUTTER:$VSCODE`
   - `export PATH`
3. If you're using nano as I suggested, do a `control + x` on your keyboard to exit.
4. press `Y` to save your changes.
5. In the terminal type `source ~/.bash_profile` to refresh your bash profile/environment variables.

Now you can navigate to any directory and call the files in your path.

Note:

- Swap out `FLUTTER` and `VSCODE` for your variable names of choice.
- You would only need to use `sudo` if you're not using the admin account.

Comment: This is my favorite way, it's the cleanest solution.

Comment: why the ```\``` after ```:```

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, it has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo CPATH=/usr/include/linux/:/usr/src/linux-headers-5.17.0-1-common/include/linux/ vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.